# git rebase [branch] AT entry point

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have in my current local branch 10 commits:

- Commit 1 <<< oldest commit
- Commit 2
- ...
- Commit 9
- Commit 10 <<<< latest commit

I want to do `git rebase other-branch` but i dont want it to put it as the "oldest commit", meaning I dont want it to come in before "Commit 1".

I want to put it right before the latest commit, so after `git rebase other-branch` there will be

- Commit 9
- .......New commits here
- Commit 10

I thought this would be possible, because we can use `git rebase -i` to move around commit order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will re-write the history of your branch, but you can accomplish this with:

```
git reset --hard COMMIT9SHA
git merge other-branch
git cherry-pick COMMIT10SHA
```

If you want to avoid a merge-commit, you could first switch to `other-branch` and rebase it off of `COMMIT9SHA`:

```
git checkout other-branch
git rebase COMMIT9SHA
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for that warning of re-writing history, mine is local branch so it's ok right now. My "Commit 10" is the only commit on this branch that is new. The previous 9 commits were `git rebase branch1` `git rebase branch2`, so I was trying to avoid doing a `git reset --hard origin/master` and then doing the reverse `git rebase` process (`git rebase other-branch` `git rebase branch2` `git rebase branch1`). Will this chery-pick process above accomplish this reverse rebase process? I'm trying to avoid merge commit, by doing rebase only.

Comment: Yes, the cherry-pick will always avoid a merge-commit. If you rebase the `other-branch` to `COMMIT9SHA` first, the merge will be a "fast-forward" merge, and not result in a merge-commit

Comment: Here's another handy tip: Before doing any of these operations, first run `git branch save`. Then, try some experimental commands. If things go wrong, all you need to do is `git reset --hard save` and you are back to where you started from. I often do this when I want to try something new and want a quick "undo"

Comment: Thank you Jonathan very much! I learned `cherry-pick` here and `reset save`!